# instantclick.js stops other jquery functions

Tags: jquery

I am using `instantclick.js` in my website but at the time when i include on the page near `</body>` as below:

```
<script src="instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant></script>
<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script>
```

then other jquery plugins do not work. For e.g, if i have `autocomplete` API by Google then it does not work and when i refresh the page then it starts working.

Can anybody let me know why it is happening because when i remove `instantclick`then all works fine?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors caused by `instantclick.js` which is affecting the execution of your other scripts?

Comment: There is no error displayed in console.. i have read `instantclick` documentation and that works on Pajax ... i think `<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script> ` can cause the issues.. what say?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan .... Now i got error like as below    1. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'geocomplete' (For autocomplete)       2. You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. (For displaying google map in iframe)

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that to achieve preloading, InstantClick hijacks the browser’s page change mechanism with pjax. The browser doesn’t change pages anymore, InstantClick does. Your website really becomes a single-page application.

In this environment, other scripts can’t rely on the usual browser loading cycle, when this poses a problem you have to tweak them to make them work with InstantClick. Instructions for doing this (not specific to jQuery plugins) are available here: http://instantclick.io/scripts

Comment: I tried each method but not seems working.. Can you build one page having google autocomplete and instantclisk.js

Comment: note that if the username of the answerer doesn't lie, here we have the creator of instantclick